# JS Regex for ignoring all special characters but space and hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

Using "test" function, i want to check for whether the alphabet only (a-zA-Z) string contains any special characters other than spaces and hyphens.

Note that i am using this regex inside JavaScript.

#### Should Match:

```
- string = A B
 - string = A-B
 - string = ABC XYZ-ASD A
```

#### Should Not Match:

```
 - string = ABC*
 - string = AB IC-B_
 - string = AB C$%^
 - string = - //hyphen/s only
 - string = ABC-
```

Currently, my regex is:

```
/[a-z][\s|-][a-z]/i
```

Can someone please suggest changes to this to ignore those special characters cases.

Thank you!

Comment: Try: `/^[a-zA-Z -]*$/`

Comment: Thanks. tried, but it also successfully allows only hyphens as well, which i want to restrict. Edited my question.

Comment: Requirements are still not clear: can there be multiple hyphens? is there a minimal number of characters? (your examples shows at least two characters). Try to think about all the edge cases that you want to support - it'll help you creating more tight requirements. Without understanding exactly what you're trying to achieve no answer here can be correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a character class that includes `a-z`, spaces, and hyphens, and check to see that the whole string is composed of only those characters, by repeating it from the start of the string (`^`) to the end (`$`):

```js
const re = /^[a-z -]+$/i;
[
  'A-B',
  'ABC XYZ-ASD A',
  'ABC*',
  'AB IC-B_',
  'AB C$%^'
].forEach((str) => {
    console.log(
      str + ' ' + (re.test(str) ? 'Pass' : 'Fail')
    )
  });
```

To additionally ensure that the string is not composed of all hyphens, negative lookahead from the beginning of the string for `-` repeated until the end of the string:

```js
const re = /^(?!-+$)[a-z -]+$/i;
[
  'A-B',
  'ABC XYZ-ASD A',
  'ABC*',
  'AB IC-B_',
  'AB C$%^',
  '--------'
].forEach((str) => {
    console.log(
      str + ' ' + (re.test(str) ? 'Pass' : 'Fail')
    )
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. tried, but it also successfully allows only hyphens as well, which i want to restrict. Edited my question.

Comment: See edit, add negative lookahead to the beginning of the string

Comment: That's great! Please don't mind, as i am only building these up now, as i think some of those cases through. How would you edit this, If this is further enhanced to not allow a string like "ABC-"?

Comment: Use `[a-z ]` at the end, right before the `$`, to ensure the last character isn't a hyphen

Comment: This: /^(?!-+$)[a-z -]+[a-z ]$/i  ?

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton! Appreciate it.

Comment: At the end: /^[a-z](?!-+$)[a-z -]+[a-z ]$/i
Edited for it to also not allow strings like "-ADC".

Hope I have not over complicated this query. 
Thanks again!

Comment: Since you're requiring non-hyphen characters at the beginning and end already, you can remove the negative lookahead group, since you already know the string won't be all hyphens

Comment: Yep. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like this?

```
^[a-zA-Z-\s]*$
```

Updated :

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]+-*[a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

Comment: Thanks. tried, but it also successfully allows only hyphens as well, which i want to restrict. Edited my question.

Comment: Can you try the updated code and see if it satisfies your requirement?